# Apply bold formatting to specific text on Powerpoint textbox programmatically

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a code that iterates through all the shapes in a Powerpoint presentation (single slide), finds the one that is a textbox and checks whether it is the one I want to replace the text with (and does so if it is, obviously).

All that is working fine, but I want to set the text bold in 2 parts of the text: the name of the person and the name of the course (it's a diploma). I have tried adjusting the ideas/code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965551/apply-font-formatting-to-powerpoint-text-programmatically) answer, but to no success.

Could anybody help me?
Below is the code I have:

```
Presentation certificadoCOM = powerpointApp.Presentations.Open(@"C:\Users\oru1ca\Desktop\certCOM.pptx");
// iterates through all shapes
foreach (Shape shape in certificadoCOM.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Range().Shapes)
{
    // gets the name of the shape and checks whether is a textbox
    string shapeName = shape.Name;
    if (shapeName.StartsWith("Text Box"))
    {
        // gets the text from the shape, and if it's the one to change, replace the text
        string shapeText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
        if (shapeText.StartsWith("Concedemos"))
        {
             shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Concedemos à Sra. " + nomeP[i] + ",\n representando [...]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = true;` ?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I don't want *all* the text to be bold.

Comment: From the example you have provided, `TextRange` has selection methods such as `.Words(1)`, use them to select the text before you apply the bold attribute?
`shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(1).Font.Bold`
You can calculate how many words are between the name and the start of the string by splitting the first string in the concatenation and counting the elements.
`"Concedemos à Sra. ".Split(' ').Count()`

Comment: @KieranDevlin great, this worked. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextRange` has methods to select a range of text within the `TextFrame`.
For example, `.Words(int)` will select a selection of words (a set of characters separated via spaces) which you can then apply styles to (in this case `.Bold`.

Code example:

```
//Set the first 3 words as bold.
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(3).Font.Bold = true;
```